# Continue processing/execution while HTTP connection is lost (Web Server/GlassFish)

Tags: glassfish, nginx, webserver, cherokee

I got this question regarding web server (such as nginx, Cherokee or Oracle iPlanet) and Java containers (such as GlassFish): Can we control what happens to the connection if the user drops an unfinished connection?

When a browser opens an HTTP/HTTPS connection to a server, it hits the web server (nginx, Cherokee or Oracle iPlanet) and then reverse proxies to the Java container (GlassFish). The Java application then executes and does quite a lot of things such as calculation and finally needs to write to, say, 3 different databases. If it has finished writing to the 1st database - but not yet to the 2nd and 3rd database - and the user closes the connection (by closing the browser window, or looses a network connection, etc.) what will happen to the process?

Specifically, I would like the process to CONTINUE until it finishes executing all the code. I know of one way is to spin off the process on a new thread, but then this will incur computation costs. So, are there any settings/config I can do to make sure it will continue to execute even though the user has broken the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nginx, you can set [proxy_ignore_client_abort](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_ignore_client_abort) on; and it will not close the connection to the backend if the client closes its connection.

Comment: Great! Any help (similar settings/config) for Cherokee and Oracle iPlanet (Sun Java Web Server)?

Comment: I've never used either of those servers, so I can't help you with them, sorry.